# I was implementing a file system in C and I got some errors below help me. I have pasted my question code and error below

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, declaration

question:
ou will develop and implement a small file system (“FS”). It is similar to some
of the basics of Unix as well as CP/M file systems.
Your file system will not be part of an operating system, but, similar to most
modern file systems, it will run in several different operating systems to
provide a “portable” file system.

Details:
Your FS will use a file (for example “disk01”), rather than directly using
a physical flash or disk, to store data.

You may have several disk-like files (for example: disk01, disk02),
used to store data.

The data stored in disk01 may be a user’s programs, text files,
other data files, or any type of binary information. In addition to the data
stored, your FS will need to store other, meta-information, such as free space
(blocks), directory details, and possibly other information. The FS directory is flat
(one level) fixed sized, has a user name associated with each file, and has fixed
sized “blocks” (entries).
You should use fixed size blocks (similar to disk blocks) of size 256 (or 1KB,
your choice, examples based on 256) bytes to store files and all meta-data
in your “disk”.
(Your “disk” (for example “disk01” is logically divided into a number of “sectors”,
which are fixed size blocks. Everything that is stored (persistent) is in these
blocks)

Your program (the “FS” executable) should provide the following operations:
(These operations deal with the “disk”, not individual user files)
Createfs #ofblocks – creates a filesystem (disk) with #ofblocks size, each 256 bytes
For example Createfs 250 creates a “virtual disk”, a file that will be initialized to
250 blocks of 256 bytes each. It is created in memory, and initialized.

Formatfs #filenames #DABPTentries
For example Formatfs 64 48 reserves space for 64 file names and 48 file meta data,
Note that some file names may “point” to the same file metadata, in this example
there can only be 48 unique files.

Savefs name– save the “disk” image in a file “name”
Openfs name- use an existing disk image
For example Savefs disk01 or Openfs disk01
These commands same the memory “image” (contents) to an external file,
in this example, it is called disk01, but can be called anything, the openfs
command retrieves the image/contents from the file and puts into memory.

List – list files (and other meta-information) in a FS
List what is in “your” directory

Remove name –remove named file from fs
Delete a user file, should reclaim the directory entry and file sectors

Rename oldname newname – rename a file stored in the FS
Just change user file name

Put ExternalFile – put (store) Host OS file into the disk
Get ExternalFile – get disk file, copy from “disk” to host OS file system
These operations put and get a user file from “outside” to and from your file system

User name – show/change name of user who owns this file
Link/Unlink – Unix style file linking
These are some more, common, meta operations, only changes something in directory,
not the data file contents

Bonus: Set/Use file permissions for r/w/x, implement subdirectories, “check disk”
Implement in either the “Go” or “Rust” programming language (20 to 75 point bonus)

Implementation:

(Note: these names and acronyms are hints, there are other methods and data structures
that may also work.)

Your FS should have 4 (or more, if easier to implement) sections:
A FileNameTable (FNT), a directory and a disk attribute/block pointer table (DABPT),
and the data blocks.

The FNT should be of size allocated, each entry should contain a 50 char
(maximum) file name and an inode pointer (index to DABPT)(blocks).

The DABPT should be allocated from disk blocks, 4 entries per block, where each entry
should contain a file meta-information (FileSize, last time+date (secs), pointers to
data blocks), user name

The Block Pointer Table has direct pointers to data blocks, and one additional
pointer to another entry in the Table, if needed (for big files), these may be
chained for very large files. (Similar to CP/M extents)

Since disks (and some meta-information) are fixed size, many small or one
large file might not fit on the “disk”. File names, file attributes and other file
information stored in FS are restrictive (for example, file creation time).

code:

```
#define FILE_SIZE 56
#define SIZE_OF_BLOCK    256
#define MAX_LINK     10
#define TIME_LENGTH   100

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Table_function
{
  //name of the file being stored
  char fileName[FILE_SIZE];
  // pointer to iNode
    Table_bp iNode;
} Table_function;
typedef struct Table_bp
{
  //The size of the file
  int size_file;
  //The variable for the index to dataBlock
  int dataBlockPointer;
  //for checking when last modified
  char DTmodified[TIME_LENGTH];
} Table_bp;
struct Link
{
  char linkName[FILE_SIZE];
    Table_bp *linkedFile;
} Link;
struct FileSystem
{
  //File system name
  char name_of_fs[FILE_SIZE];
  //Maps data slot for ABPT
  int *ABPTMap;
  //variable for the total number of Data blocks in System
  int number_of_blocks;
  //Maps  data slot for FNT
  int *FNTMap;
  //variable to keep track of available FNT blocks
  int FNT;
  //Keep track of available ABPT blocks 
  int ABPT;
  //Maps  data slot for datablock CPM style
  int *dataBlockMap;
   //Structure for holding initial files
    struct Table_bp *pointer_table;
  struct Table_function *files;
  char **dataBlocks;
  struct Link link[MAX_LINK];
} FileSystem;
struct FileSystem FS;
void formatFS(char name[FILE_SIZE],int pointer_entries_num,int FNT)
{
    printf(" File System created with \n name:%s\n no. of pointers: %d\n no of files:%d \n",name,pointer_entries_num,FNT);
     // number of pointer entries   
   FS.ABPT=pointer_entries_num;
    //file name system storing
    strcpy(FS.name_of_fs,name);
    // number of files
    FS.FNT=FNT; 
    //initialization
    FS.files=malloc(FNT*sizeof(struct Table_function));
    FS.pointer_table=malloc(pointer_entries_num*sizeof(struct Table_bp));
    FS.FNTMap= malloc(FNT*sizeof(int*));
    FS.ABPTMap= malloc(pointer_entries_num*sizeof(int*));
}
void createFS(int number_of_blocks)
{
  int j;
  char **d_holder;   
   int i;
    printf("Selected Datablocks: %d\n",number_of_blocks);
    FS.number_of_blocks=number_of_blocks;
    d_holder=(char**) malloc(SIZE_OF_BLOCK*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<number_of_blocks;i++)
    {
      d_holder[i]=(char*)malloc(number_of_blocks*sizeof(char));
    }
    FS.dataBlockMap= malloc(number_of_blocks*sizeof(int*));
    FS.dataBlocks=d_holder;
}
//main function
void execute() 
{
    char name_of_fs[FILE_SIZE];
     int choice=-1;
     char trasher[FILE_SIZE];
    char deleter[FILE_SIZE];
  while(1)
  {
    printf("1) Exit\n");
    printf("2) Create FileSystem\n"); 
    printf("3) Format FileSystem\n"); 
    printf("4) Delete a file\n");
    printf("5) Trash a file\n");
    printf("Choice?: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    printf("\n");
    switch(choice)
    {
      case 1: // exit if not selected 1 or 2
        exit(0);
      // creating the file system
      case 2: 
        printf("Enter the number of data blocks in the system: \n");
        int block_num; 
        scanf("%d",&block_num);
        // the below call will create the file system with user specified number of blocks
        createFS(block_num); 
        // success message od disk created successfully
        printf("***Disk Created***\n\n"); 
        break;
      case 3: // formatting the file system
        printf("*** formatting of File system in progress...\n");
        printf("File System Name: \n");
       // file system to be formatted       
       scanf("%s",name_of_fs);
        printf("Block Pointers Number?: \n"); 
        int numBlockPointers;
        int numFiles;
        scanf("%d",&numBlockPointers);
        printf("Number of files?: \n"); 
        scanf("%d",&numFiles);
         // format the file system with the specified parameters
        formatFS(name_of_fs,numBlockPointers,numFiles);
        printf("***Disk Formatted***\n\n"); // formatted successfully
        break;
        case 4:
          printf("File name?");
          scanf("%s",deleter);
          printf("%s File deleted\n\n\n",deleter);
          break;
        case 5:
          printf("File name?");
          scanf("%s",trasher);
          printf("%s File Trashed\n\n\n",trasher);
          break;
    }
  }
}
int main()
{
  execute();
  return 0;
}
```

error:

main.c:18:5: error: unknown type name ‘Table_bp’
18 |     Table_bp iNode

Comment: Do not copy paste your school labs and expect stack overflow to solve them !!!

Comment: You need to move `typedef struct Table_bp` to be above `typedef struct Table_function` where it is used.

Comment: `// pointer to iNode` Also, what you have is not a pointer. `Table_bp *iNode;` is a pointer to the struct, `Table_bp iNode;` is the entire struct.

Comment: Has everyone here completed this same assignment? My advice is plan in detail what the free parameters should be before writing a bit of code. Asserts will be nice. A quick GraphViz output will save many hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the name `Table_bp` in this structure definition

```
typedef struct Table_function
{
  //name of the file being stored
  char fileName[FILE_SIZE];
  // pointer to iNode
    Table_bp iNode;
} Table_function;
```

though the name `Table_bp` is not declared yet.

Place this typedef declaration with the structure `Table_bp` definition

```
typedef struct Table_bp
{
  //The size of the file
  int size_file;
  //The variable for the index to dataBlock
  int dataBlockPointer;
  //for checking when last modified
  char DTmodified[TIME_LENGTH];
} Table_bp;
```

above the definition of the structure `struct Table_function`.